# Xcode 6 Beta 5 If Statement not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

In Xcode 6 Beta 4 I could check if a variable is of a certain type with this line:

```
if advanceDetails.objectForKey(selectedSectionName) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>  {
```

Now, in Xcode 6 Beta 5 I get the error:

```
Type 'Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType.Protocol'
```

What is the new way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `is` instead of `as?` for your comparison. Also note that as of Beta 5, if you're checking for `nil` you need to explicitly use `if object == nil` or if `object != nil`, which is the error you're seeing.

Comment: Ah, if I remember correctly, one had to check for nil that way in Beta 2 and they changed that for Beta 3 and 4.

Answer (score 2):

That is because Optionals now need to be compared to `nil` explicitly. However, you should use `is` instead:

```
if advanceDetails.objectForKey(selectedSectionName) is Dictionary<String, AnyObject>  {
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't check for nil like this anymore:

```
if myOptional {...
```

You need to explicitly do this:

```
if myOptional != nil {...
```

Answer (score 1):

The release notes say:

> Optionals no longer conform to the BooleanType (formerly `LogicValue`) protocol, so they may no longer be used in place of boolean expressions (they must be explicitly compared with v != nil). This resolves confusion around Bool? and related types, makes code more explicit about what test is expected, and is more consistent with the rest of the language.
>
> Note that ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional still includes some BooleanType functionality. This 
>   issue will be resolved in a future beta. (17110911)